# How to Set Video Frameset using Android Code

Tags: android, video, frame-rate

I am developing an Android Application for Video Recording. Here I my Android Device has 15FPS for video recording. so My Question is can I decrease the FPS using Android code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you used [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#setVideoFrameRate%28int%29)?